# Output from function to console, preserving color

Tags: powershell, console

I'm running msbuild from powershell, inside a function:

```
function Run-MSBuild()
{
    msbuild.exe (lots of params)
}

Run-MSBuild
```

Works great, and I see colored MSBuild output on my console. Now, I want to know how long it took:

```
$time = Measure-Command { Run-MSBuild }
```

Works, but I don't see the MSBuild output anymore.

**Attempt 1:** Pipe to `Write-Host`:

```
function Run-MSBuild()
{
    msbuild.exe (lots of params) | Write-Host
}
```

**Result 1:** I see MSBuild output on my console, but color is lost.

**Attempt 2:** Replace `Measure-Command`:

```
$timer = [diagnostics.stopwatch]::startnew()
Run-MSBuild
$time = $timer.Elapsed
```

**Result 2:** Works, but kinda ugly.

Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Include the timing command in the function?

```
function Run-MSBuild
{
    $start = Get-Date
    msbuild.exe $args
    $End = Get-Date

    $End-$Start
}
```

Comment: If `Write-Host` isn't preserving colour, then this seems like the only sensible solution.